# Automating Manual Import process

Tags: php, import, automation

I am a "Newbie". I have a site written with the free version. The manual import works fine (after reindexing). I want to automate that process to run every night. How? Thanks, Randy

More info: the manual import/reindex in the Magento control panel works fine for my purpose. However, I need some way of automating that process for a unattended nightly import of some 6000 products. Our website was written by a developing firm that recently left us with an uncompleted web. We are trying to finish up on our own.

Thanks, Randy

Answer (score 1):

You will need to understand this article about [importing products programatically](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/) and then make it work with a CSV and a cronjob.

Without medium/high knowledge of the platform this will cost you some time, so as an advice from a business/time perspective, hire someone who can do this (this is not the correct place for hiring people).